# Web Site title - apply different color to each letter

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attempting to apply CSS styles using Javascript to the title of the web page. I can't change the overall structure of the XMHTL, but I am allowed to add CSS and Java to change the appearance.

I want to apply a different color to each letter in the site's title.

I've tried this example:

https://codepen.io/tomhodgins/pen/YJZyPr

I attempted to add a class to an existing element to use the above example. I tried adding the class using a var statement and by directly altering the XML template. I've also tried a couple of other examples here that target individual letters within an element.

I need to apply individual CSS color to each individual letter in the h1 tag inside the Header1 tag.

```
<div class="widget Header" data-version="2" id="Header1">
<div class="header-widget">
<div>
<h1>
MyTitle
</h1>
</div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I want each letter of MyTitle to be a different color.

This works to change all the text to red; for example, but I haven't been able to target each letter individually yet.

```
#Header1 h1{
color: #900;
}
```

EDIT:

The title is located with a widget which may or may not allow editing. Editing it may corrupt the template.

```
<b:section id='header' name='Header' showaddelement='false'>
                  <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='MyTitle (Header)' type='Header' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                      <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'/>
                      <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>0</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>-1</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='useImage'>false</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='imagePlacement'>BEHIND</b:widget-setting>
                      <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>0</b:widget-setting>
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
    <div class='header-widget'>
      <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement in {&quot;REPLACE&quot;, &quot;BEFORE_DESCRIPTION&quot;}' name='image'/>
      <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement not in {&quot;REPLACE&quot;, &quot;BEFORE_DESCRIPTION&quot;}' name='title'/>
      <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement != &quot;REPLACE&quot;' name='description'/>
    </div>
    <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement == &quot;BEHIND&quot;' name='behindImageStyle'/>
  </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='behindImageStyle'>
    <b:if cond='data:sourceUrl'>
      <b:include cond='data:this.image' data='{                    image: data:this.image,                    selector: &quot;.header-widget&quot;                  }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
      <style type='text/css'>
        .header-widget {
          background-position: <data:blog.locale.languageAlignment/>;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
      </style>
    </b:if>
  </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='description'>
    <p>
      <data:this.description/>
    </p>
  </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='image'>
          <b:include name='super.image'/>
          <!-- If we are replacing the title, force it to render anyway, and it'll be hidden in CSS. -->
          <b:include cond='data:this.imagePlacement == &quot;REPLACE&quot;' name='title'/>
        </b:includable>
                    <b:includable id='title'>
          <div>
            <b:class cond='data:this.imagePlacement == &quot;REPLACE&quot;' name='replaced'/>
            <b:include name='super.title'/>
          </div>
        </b:includable>
                  </b:widget>
                </b:section>
```

ADDITIONAL EDIT:

I forgot to mention that the site's main title is also a link to the home page. The original answer below did not take this link into account thus the link was removed. I modified the original answer by reinserting the link to the home page. The code below uses a dummy URL.

```
<script>
const h1 = document.querySelector('#Header1 h1'),
  colors = ['#E53238', '#0064D3', '#F5AF02', '#86B817'];

const html = h1.textContent.trim().split('').map((s, i)=>{
   return `<span style="color:${colors[i % colors.length]}">${s}</span>`
}).join('')

h1.innerHTML = "<a href="https://mybigcoolsitetosee.com/">" + html + "</a>"
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array of colors and adding them to inline style

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('#Header1 h1'),
  colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple', 'pink', 'yellow'];

const html = h1.textContent.trim().split('').map((s, i)=>{
   return `<span style="color:${colors[i % colors.length]}">${s}</span>`
}).join('')

h1.innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div id="Header1">
  <h1>
    MyTitle
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Very similar to the answer I was considering, but (IMO), it would be more fun to have the colors assigned randomly.

Comment: Just saw this solution from @charlietfl, it its very similar the one I included in my answer, and actually, to make the colors randomly you could change the names of the collors inside the array for variables like: 

var color01 = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

var color02 = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

that would do the job...

Comment: Thanks, that works.The script did not work when placed inside the head tag. I needed to place it below all of the content of template just above the </body></html> tags for it to override the template's code.

Answer (score 1):

Using this example as you mentioned: https://codepen.io/tomhodgins/pen/YJZyPr

But instead of setting

```
h1.letter[--nth-letter="1"] { background: red; }
h1.letter[--nth-letter="2"] { background: orange; }
```

set it as

```
h1.letter[--nth-letter="1"] { color: red; }
h1.letter[--nth-letter="2"] { color: orange; }
```

and so on...

However, if you can't change the html in anyway you could do it with pure javascript like:

```js
var title = document.querySelector('h1'),
  options = ['blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'brown', 'red', 'yellow'];

var result = title.textContent.trim().split('').map((color, i)=>{
   return `<span style="color:${options[i % options.length]}">${ color }</span>`
}).join('')

title.innerHTML = result
```

````html
```
<div class="widget Header" data-version="2" id="Header1">
<div class="header-widget">
<div>
<h1>
MyTitle
</h1>
</div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```
````

Comment: In order for that to work I would need to apply a new class of "letter" to the h1 tag inside the XHTML template, which doe snot appear possible. I attempted to add the class using element.classList.add but that did not work. I also added this class to area of the template for the title and that did not work.

Comment: Just added a solution including spans inside the H1 tag with pure JS... Maybe that is gonna work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code to your source, and change it what you want

```
const h1 = document.querySelector('#Header1 h1'),
  colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple', 'pink', 'yellow'];

const html = h1.textContent.trim().split('').map((s, i)=>{
   return `<span style="color:${colors[i % colors.length]}">${s}</span>`
}).join('')

h1.innerHTML = html
```

And also this code:

```
<div id="Header1">
  <h1>
    MyTitle
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to take advantage of the fact that you can easily convert a String into an Array.
In your case you're going to use jQuery (or vanilla js such as getElementById() ) to grab the text you want to style, and then use javascript to iterate through the string and assign a new color to each one.

For example:

```
var a = $("h1").text();
$("h1").empty();
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
 $("h1").append("<span class = 'color"+i+"'>"+a[i]+"</span>");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crt829fp/2/

Comment: Question isn't tagged jQuery